# cppnet-lib http client works on one system, not another

Tags: c++, boost

I've been working on some code on a machine running Ubuntu Mint. I'm using the boost::network::http::client to retrieve a web page and work with the data. Everything is fine.

I recently installed Kubuntu on another system. I used apt-get to install lib-boost-all-dev and libcppnetlib-dev.

My program compiles on the Kubuntu machine, but locks forever trying to extract the body(response). Here is an example of what my code is doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <boost/network/uri.hpp>

namespace http = boost::network::http;
namespace uri  = boost::network::uri;
using namespace std;

int main() {

   string url = "http://127.0.0.1";

   http::client client;
   http::client::request request(url);
   http::client::response response = client.get(request);
   // Next line stalls forever
   string data = static_cast<std::string>(body(response));
   // Never gets here
   return 0;
}
```

Again, this sort of thing seems to work fine on my Mint machine, but not on the new machine I just setup. What are some things I should look at or try to resolve this? Thank you.

In case it helps, here's a gdb dump of where it's locking.

```
gdb) run
Starting program: /home/bi/Projects/yahtest/prog 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff5d01700 (LWP 27239)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5500700 (LWP 27240)]
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
185     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
#1  0x0000000000412bb4 in boost::condition_variable::wait (this=0x6c5b00, 
    m=...) at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:73
#2  0x0000000000414ea0 in boost::detail::shared_state_base::wait_internal (
    this=0x6c5aa0, lk=..., rethrow=true)
    at /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:327
#3  0x0000000000414f6d in boost::detail::shared_state_base::wait (
    this=0x6c5aa0, rethrow=true) at /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:346
#4  0x00000000004303ac in boost::detail::shared_state<std::string>::get_sh (
    this=0x6c5aa0) at /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:672
#5  0x000000000042c991 in boost::shared_future<std::string>::get (
    this=0x7fffffffd790) at /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:1897
#6  0x0000000000427a70 in boost::network::http::async_message<boost::network::http::tags::http_async_8bit_udp_resolve>::body (this=0x7fffffffd6d0)
    at /usr/include/boost/network/protocol/http/message/async_message.hpp:121
#7  0x0000000000420bfd in boost::network::http::impl::body_wrapper<boost::network::http::basic_response<boost::network::http::tags::http_async_8bit_udp_resolve> >::operator std::string (this=0x7fffffffd5b0)
    at /usr/include/boost/network/protocol/http/message/wrappers/body.hpp:29
#8  0x0000000000410162 in main () at main.cpp:21
(gdb)
```